# STM32 and SDFat - Can't create file in directory in SD

Tags: sd-card, sd, stm32

I'm using the SdFat.h library on a STM32 and I can successfully create a file in the root directory using *SD.open("test.txt", FILE_WRITE);* but my code fails to create *SD.open("DATA/data_test.txt", FILE_WRITE);* in a directory.
Here's the piece of code that successfully creates a file in the root:

```
String final_book_name = upload_book_name + ".txt";
if (SD.exists(final_book_name.c_str())) {
  SD.remove(final_book_name.c_str());
}
tft.println(final_book_name); // This successfully prints "test.txt"
book_file = SD.open(final_book_name, FILE_WRITE);
if (SD.exists(final_book_name.c_str())) {
  tft.print("Created file");
} else {
  tft.print("Failed to create/replace\nfile!");
}
```

and here's the piece of the code that fails to create a file in a directory:

```
if (!SD.exists(DATA_DIR)) {
  SD.mkdir(DATA_DIR);
}
String final_book_name = upload_book_name + ".txt";
String book_data_path = DATA_DIR;
book_data_path += "/data_" + final_book_name;
if (SD.exists(book_data_path.c_str())) {
  SD.remove(book_data_path.c_str());
}
tft.println(book_data_path); // This successfully prints "DATA/data_test.txt"
File book_data_file = SD.open(book_data_path, FILE_WRITE);
if (SD.exists(book_data_path.c_str())) {
  book_data_file.print(upload_book_font);
  book_data_file.print("|");
  book_data_file.print("0");
  book_data_file.close();
} else{
  tft.print("Failed to create/replace\ndata file!");
  if (SD.exists(final_book_name.c_str())) {
    SD.remove(final_book_name.c_str());
  }
}
```

Comment: Try it with `/DATA/test.txt` I remember SD library uses the classic 8.3 filenames and `data_test.txt` is invalid

Comment: @DataFiddler I'm using SdFat.h with Long Names (which allows names up to 255 characters)

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I'm not creating the directory folder properly. When I checked the SD card from another device, the DATA folder was invalid, and creating it manually works. I'll look for a solution and post an update.

UPDATE: https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=421131.0 I'll try this tomorrow but it'll probably fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you have given no variable for `DATA_DIR`

```
String book_data_path = DATA_DIR;
book_data_path += "/data_" + final_book_name;
```

so your resulting path looks like

```
DATA_DIR + "/data_" + final_book_name
```

IF `DATA_DIR = "/"` then it would be `"/" + "/data_" + final_book_name`

As tip do not use the string class but char arrays

definition

```
 const char[] DATA_DIR = "/books";  
 char book_data_path [128] = {'\0'};
 char final_book_name [13] =  {'\0'}; // IF no LFN support is used its 8.3 !!!
 const char upload_book_name[] = "my_book";
 strcpy (final_book_name, upload_book_name);
 strcat (final_book_name, ".txt");
 Serial.println(final_book_name);
```

If you want long filr namesupport us SDFat library or enable LFB withSD lib (whichneeds about 35% ,ore memory as SDfat (when using long file names).
**EDIT**
As you are using SDFat and I do not know which version/fork there is abug with writing to subdirectories. Please check the following:

To check run the `SdFat\examples\DirectoryFunctions` and watch your serial monitor for the results
SdFile.cpp. At line 782 and 1452, you have (in my version):

```
if (block <= m_vol->cacheBlockNumber()
  && block < (m_vol->cacheBlockNumber() + nb)) {
```

The working code has:

```
if (m_vol->cacheBlockNumber() <= block
  && block < (m_vol->cacheBlockNumber() + nBlock)) {
```

If you have the upper version change it and it should work

**EDIT 2** Work around for buggy SDFat lib
Here is a workaround code

```
const char DATA_DIR [] = "data";
char final_book_name[128] ={'\0'};
char book_data_path [256] ={'\0'};

if (!SD.exists(DATA_DIR)) {
  SD.mkdir(DATA_DIR);
  SD.chdir(DATA_DIR);
}

strcpy (final_book_name, upload_book_name);
 strcat (final_book_name, ".txt";
String book_data_path = DATA_DIR;

strcpy(book_data_path, "data_");
strcat(book_data_path, final_book_name);

if (SD.exists(book_data_path)) {
  SD.remove(book_data_path);
}
SD.mkdir(book_data_path);
SD.chdir(book_data_path);

tft.println(DATA_DIR);
tft.println(book_data_path); // This successfully prints "DATA/data_test.txt"
File book_data_file = SD.open(final_book_name, FILE_WRITE);
if (SD.exists(final_book_name)) {
  book_data_file.print(upload_book_font);
  book_data_file.print("|");
  book_data_file.print("0");
  book_data_file.close();
} else{
  tft.print("Failed to create/replace\ndata file!");
  if (SD.exists(final_book_name)) {
    SD.remove(final_book_name);
  }
}
```

Comment: DATA_DIR is "DATA". I don't see the solution in your answer. I will make my Strings to characters, that's a good idea but what about my main issue here?

Comment: Sorry, it's still unclear to me what I should do. I'm using STM32, not an Arduino and I don't have a Serial Monitor. I will try downloading a newer SdFat version.

Comment: I downloaded the newest version of SdFat from here: https://github.com/greiman/SdFat and ran it, but it still fails to create a file in a subdirectory

Comment: I could try to do SD.chdir(DATA_DIR); but I'm not sure how that works exactly and if even that's the problem. I don't think SD.chdir(DATA_DIR); is necessary

Comment: I tried with SD.chdir(DATA_DIR); (as far as I know how to use it) but it failed. (it created the file in the root, not in the dir)

Comment: Use my EDIT 2 leave it for the moment as it is

Comment: "As you do not want to fix your obviously buggy SD.lib" I've never said that. How do I fix it, I don't have serial monitor?

Comment: Sorry for my cynism. But you reveal info step by step which should be in you question from the beginning.On the stm32you will have to rewrite the progfor your Tft. So have you tested the work around.On an STM32 the lib isknown to give problems

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. Thanks for trying to help me out. I will look at the code you posted and I'll try to implement some parts of it tomorrow. Thanks for the help.